# Obtain equation of right circular cylinder

Tags: geometry

Obtain equation of right circular cylinder with the circle through points $(a,0,0),(0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$ as the guiding curve.

I proceeded by considering this circle as intersection of sphere from the given points along with origin and the plane $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$ and obtained the equation of axis of the cylinder as it is supposed to pass through the centre of sphere and is perpendicular to the plane. But can not proceed after that as need to calculate the radius of the circle through these points and unable to get the radius.

Is the approach wrong or needs some change?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Proceeding as you did, the sphere passing through the three points and the origin is:

$(x - x_c)^2 + (y - y_c)^2 + (z - z_c)^2 = R^2$

since the sphere passes through the origin, then

$R^2 = x_c^2 + y_c^2 + z_c^2$

so that the equation of the sphere is

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 x x_c - 2 y y_c - 2 z z_c = 0 $

Substituting $(a, 0, 0), (0, b, 0), (0, 0, c) $ gives

$x_c = 1/2 a , y_c = 1/2 b, z_c = 1/2 c$

so the equation of the sphere is finally,

$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - a x -  b y -  c z = 0 $

and its Center is

$ C = \dfrac{1}{2} [ a, b, c]^T $

and its radius is

$R = \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} $

To find the radius of cylinder, we compute first the distance between $C$ and plane $x/a + y/b + z/c = 1$, and this is

$d = 1/2 / \sqrt{ 1/a^2 + 1/b^2 + 1/c^2 } $

therefore, radius of cylinder is

$r = \sqrt{R^2 - d^2}

Now, the equation of cylinder is

$(r - C)^T (I - \dfrac{{n n}^T }{ n^T n} ) (r - C) = r^2 = R^2 - d^2 $

where $n = [1/a, 1/b, 1/c]^T $

Multiplying both sides by ${n^T n}$

$(r - C)^T ( (n^T n) I - {n n}^T ) (r - C) = (n^T n) (R^2 - d^2) $

Now, $n^T n = 1/a^2 + 1/b^2 + 1/c^2$

so the right hand side is: $ 1/4 (1/a^2 + 1/b^2 + 1/c^2) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) - 1/4 $ and this is

$RHS = 1/4 ( 2 + b^2/a^2 + a^2/b^2 + c^2/a^2 + a^2 / c^2 + b^2 / c^2 + c^2 / b^2 ) $

Now calculating

$Q = ((n^T n) I - {n n}^T ) = \begin{bmatrix} 1/b^2 + 1/c^2 && -1/(ab) && -1/(ac) \\ -1/(ab) &&  1/a^2 + 1/c^2 &&    -1/(bc) \\ -1/(ac) && - 1/(bc) &&  1/a^2 + 1/b^2 \end{bmatrix} $

and

$Q C = 1/2 (  a (1/b^2 + 1/c^2) - 2 / a ,  b ( 1/a^2 + 1/c^2 ) - 2 / b , c (1/a^2 + 1/b^2) - 2 / c ) $

We end up with (after simplification):
$x^2 \left(\frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}\right) + y^2 \left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}\right) + z^2 \left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2}\right) - \frac{2xy}{ab} - \frac{2xz}{ac} - \frac{2yz}{bc} - x \left(a\left(\frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}\right) - \frac{2}{a}\right) - y \left(b\left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}\right) - \frac{2}{b}\right) - z \left(c\left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2}\right) - \frac{2}{c}\right) = 2$

And this is the equation of the cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the center of the circle that passes through $3$ given points is $(x_0, y_0, z_0).$

One of the ways to do it -

- find the equation of the plane through these $3$ points which you have already done.
- Equate the distance between the center and the $3$ points on the circle (as they are radii of the circle).
- As the center also lines on the plane, we get one more equation.

Solving these equations gives you the center of the circle and then distance to any of the $3$ points is the radius.

Axis of the cylinder is the line orthogonal to the plane and passing through the center of the circle that we just obtained.

But I find it faster to use [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system). Please see below.

Our circle is going through points $A(a,0,0), B(0,b,0), C(0,0,c)$ and it is the circumcircle of the $\triangle ABC$.

So coordinates of the center $O$ is given by $\alpha (a,0,0) + \beta (0,b,0) + \gamma (0,0,c)$
where $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$

The ratio of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is given by the sides of the triangle as follows -

$\alpha : \beta : \gamma = BC^2(AB^2+CA^2-BC^2):CA^2(AB^2+BC^2-CA^2):AB^2(BC^2+CA^2-AB^2)$

and you get $ \, \alpha : \beta : \gamma = a^2(b^2+c^2):b^2(c^2+a^2):c^2(a^2+b^2)$

Earlier we said coordinates of the center $O = \alpha (a,0,0) + \beta (0,b,0) + \gamma (0,0,c)$
where $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$

So, $O = \displaystyle (\frac{a^3(b^2+c^2)}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)}, \frac{b^3(c^2+a^2)}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)}, \frac{c^3(a^2+b^2)}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)})$

Distance from $O$ to any of the points $A, B, C$ will give you the radius.

You can also find the parametric equation of the axis of the cylinder as it is orthogonal to the plane with points $A, B$ and $C$ and it passes through point $O$.

Answer (score 0):

A point in the plane has the coordinates $u(a,0,0)+v(0,b,0)+w(0,0,c)=(ua,vb,wc)$ with $u+v+w=1$. Let us express that the center is in the plane and is equidistant from the given points:

$$(ua-a)^2+(vb)^2+(wc)^2=(ua)^2+(vb-b)^2+(wc)^2=(ua)^2+(vb)^2+(wc-c)^2$$

or after expansion and simplification,

$$a^2(1-2u)=b^2(1-2v)=c^2(1-2w).$$

Let this common value be $d^2$. Then

$${d^2}\left(\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}+\frac1{c^2}\right)=3-2=1$$ and we obtain the coordinates of the center:

$$ua=\frac a2-\frac{d^2}{2a},vb=\frac b2-\frac{d^2}{2b},wc=\frac c2-\frac {d^2}{2c}.$$

And the direction of the axis is $\left(\dfrac1a,\dfrac1b,\dfrac1c\right)$. The unit vector in the direction of the axis is $\vec t=d\left(\dfrac1a,\dfrac1b,\dfrac1c\right)$.

---

The implicit equation of the cylinder expresses that the distance of a point to the axis is the radius, i.e.

$$\|(x-ua,y-vb,z-wc)\times\vec t\|=r.$$